# How can i change the join query result to $this->paginate in cakephp

Tags: join, pagination, cakephp-2.0

This is my join query code:

```
$options['joins'] = array(
                array('table' => 'employees',
                    'alias' => 'Employees',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'foreignKey' => 'employee_id',
                    // 'fields' => 'Users.user', <- get rid of this
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'TravancoDSREmployee.emp_id = Employees.employee_id'
                    )
                )
            );
        $options['fields'] = array('TravancoDSREmployee.*','Employees.*'); // <- insert this
        $options['conditions'] = array( 'TravancoDSREmployee.created_emp_id' => $emp_id);
        $result = $this->TravancoDSREmployee->find('all', $options);
        $this->set('result', $result);
```

I want to set it with pagination.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it:

This is work for me:

```
$this->paginate['TravancoDSREmployee'] = array(
            'limit' => 3, 
            'contain' => '', 
            'conditions' => array('TravancoDSREmployee.created_emp_id' => $emp_id),
            'fields' => array('TravancoDSREmployee.*','Employees.*'),
            'joins' => array(array('table' => 'employees', 'type' => 'INNER', 'alias' => 'Employees', 'conditions' => array('TravancoDSREmployee.emp_id = Employees.employee_id')))
            );
        $result = $this->paginate('TravancoDSREmployee');
        $this->set('result',$result);
```

I refered this link for getting solution:
http://planetcakephp.org/aggregator/items/3544-using-mysql-inner-join-in-cakephp-pagination

Answer (score 1):

Please look on url given below.

http://garbers.co.za/2011/05/03/easy-way-to-generate-cakephp-habtm-joins-for-use-in-pagination/

Code You can try is

```
$fields = array('TravancoDSREmployee.*','Employees.*'); // <- insert this
$conditions = array( 'TravancoDSREmployee.created_emp_id' => $emp_id);
$joins = array();
$joins[] = array(
    'table' => 'employees',
            'alias' => 'Employees',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'foreignKey' => 'employee_id',
            // 'fields' => 'Users.user', <- get rid of this
            'conditions' => 'TravancoDSREmployee.emp_id = Employees.employee_id',
      );

$this->paginate = compact('fields' , 'joins' , 'conditions');
$result = $this->paginate('TravancoDSREmployee');
$this->set('result', $result);
```

I hope it will be helpful for you,

thanks

Comment: please print `$result` in controller file and exit. and check what result comes in it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must pass your condition to paginate property in your controller. After it, you can call paginate function. Cange your $result to become:

```
$this->paginate = array('TravancoDSREmployee' => $options);
$result = $this->paginate('TravancoDSREmployee');
$this->set('result', $result);
```

Comment: i changed the last two lines with your code...I listed the result in view...Then got error like...`Undefined index: Employees ....`

Comment: you must change your view to accomodate pagination. array returned by pagination and model->find('all'...) are different. Debug $result variable to show returned array. Also add paging navigation on your view.

Comment: no your are mistkaed..This is not the problem with pagination...The problem is around with join feature..With your code the join not working.....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17046/discussion-between-habibillah-and-kichu)